# Is it necessary to broadcast both odometry and tf data?

Tags: navigation, odometry, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Most [odometry examples](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom) I've read show reporting of both odometry and tf. Is this necessary? If you're broadcasting the robot's base_link transform via tf, doesn't that accomplish the same thing as odometry messages?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258853/is-it-necessary-to-broadcast-both-odometry-and-tf-data?/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2017-04-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the answer depends on your applications. In another word: "who needs what?".

For example, in navigation stack (other stacks may differ):

- AMCL node uses tf  for localization because it needs to match laser scans to the static map. It would be a pain to use odom topic in this case.
- Some of the motion planners in move_base needs both tf and odom for planning because they also consider the velocity data from odom.

Personally, I would think tf is a bit more complicated to use but it provides many other benefits (like timeout from last know transform, easily transforming a point from 1 frame to another, etc.), but it still depends on your applications. If you feel that odom data is good enough then there is no need to publish tf.

---

Originally posted by [DavidN](https://answers.ros.org/users/26292/davidn/) with karma: 544 on 2017-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1